# How to get rid of thoughts of grandiosness?

Tags: mindfulness, mind, right-mindfulness, mind-states

By practising the eight fold path and meditation I have been able to get over lot of suffering as a result of my past created by my mind. I am able to get over self pity, hatered, anger by following the advise of friends in this forum...

But now that I am over the past my mind has started playing new game...it starts painting pictures of grandiosness...like it presents me with illusions like i will be as great as the Buddha...I will be the Buddha and have followers...i will have super powers...i can fly etc etc...

Its getting difficult to control these thoughts in meditation...its a kind of hindrance I didnt read in any book...

I want to attain silent present moment awareness...is there any sutta which can help me with overcoming this maya of my mind?
Is there any help?

Comment: Can you please share how do you  practice maybe I will find smth really helpful

Comment: Hi D.'s, I do the silent sitting meditation....I practise as per given Ajahn Brahms book Mindfulness bliss and beyond...I kind of do Samatha meditation...sit and try to be aware of my thoughts and try not to ha e any thoughts.

Comment: with open or closed eyes?

Comment: With closed eyes....but seriously does that really matter...open or closed problem is out of control thoughts...but may be you know better...

Comment: Yes it matters,your closed eyes make you loose reference::Any teaching which teaches one to do meditation with closed eyes and teaches that the experience one gets by closed eyes is the final one, should be buried down the earth”.Vallalar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satipattana meditation is what you should practice. If you are feeling proud, simply note it until it goes away. Ex: Proud... proud... proud... or expecting... expecting... expecting... or thinking... thinking... thinking...

If you start to get worried, do the same: worrying... worrying.. worrying...

You just need to keep noting using a word that best describes what is happening at the present moment

Answer (score 1):

from my own experience with mindfulness meditation over past 10 months (and a slightly longer interest in zen buddhism and Jungian psychology), I can understand what is your struggle. 
Accepting and understanding my own self pity, hatered and anger was a big step for me, yet it has opened me to a completely new set of aspects of my personality that were hiding in the background, undeveloped and a little bit scary at first. 
But frankly, is there something that worries you about your thoughts of becoming something greater? Is it possible that you are not used to be someone better? Or that you are angry about these thoughts? That you pity yourself because your progress was undermined by these new emotions? 
For me it was exactly this. So I took a step back because I found myself in the power of emotions I was originaly trying to understand. 
The great thing about mindfulness meditation is that we are able to notice all of these emotions and thoughts (even grandiosness), understand why they appeared, cherish them for a short time and let them go. 
I wish you a lovely day!
Martin

Comment: May be your psychoanalysis about why I dont want them is right but more importantly these new thoughts are now hampering my possibility of being here and now. Earlier i lied in past...now this is fantasies of future...they are both futile...

Comment: This is interesting, because it reminds me about the presentation (on the personal growth) I was present at just 3 weeks ago. It was mentioned there that people that are used to lie to their bosses about the amount/quality of work they are doing, should at first focus on this area of their lives, because it is possible that after they quit their job (to become a freelancer) they will continue to lie to themselves and (sadly) fail in pursuing their dream. Have you ever considered a psychoanalysis before? It helped me personally to deal with the shadows of my past a lead me to mindfulness.

Comment: I dont have psychoanalyst where I live...I will see what I can do...may be search online...

Comment: Dear BodhiWalker, maybe this post on Quora will be of some help to you (I assumed area based on your profile), it mentions also some online sessions. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-a-good-psychologist-in-India#

Comment: It's nothing :) Have a nice day!